# Incorrect relative path redirection with Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to implement a reverse proxy with Nginx to get access to a web application. I met difficulties with redirections.
For instance, let's say I have a Python http server (in practice, I cannot modify the server settings / code):

```
import http.server
import socketserver

class MyHttpRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/login':
            self.path = 'login.html'
        elif self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/login')
            self.end_headers()
        return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

handler_object = MyHttpRequestHandler
serv = socketserver.TCPServer(("127.0.0.1", 8080), handler_object)
```

I have the following configuration for Nginx:

```
location /app {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

When I go to https://myip/app/, I should be redirected to https://myip/app/login. But instead of that, I am redirected to https://myip/login, which is not routed.
I tried different parameters like proxy_redirect, proxy_headers... with no success.

Comment: Try changing `http://127.0.0.1:8080` to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` (i.e. add an ending slash).

Answer (score 0):

Your python application is redirecting to `/login`, so the browser will request to

```
https://myip/login
```

Which then bypasses your `/app` location block.

I can't really give you an answer as I don't know what your requirements are, but the following will work:

Change your redirect to `/app/login`

In your case, you need to tell Nginx that you want to append the URI in the forwarded request:

In your Nginx config, add the $request_url to the forwarded request:

```
location /app {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
}
```

To me, this is a somewhat brittle solution, that assumes you need to have `/app` as your location.

Ideally, your should reverse-proxy the root URI `location /` to the python app to remove these and other potential anomalies. You can then create specific exceptions in the Nginx config if there are certain requests (eg CDN) that should not go to the python application.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
    > location /app {
    >         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/; 
}
```

the trailing slash will forward your request with the path.